# What's the correct answer to this review item?

Tags: discussion, review

I was [reviewing this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/21735) and I'm not sure what I should answer.

With 2 downvotes, it's certainly not very helpful. I would downvote as well, because "implement yourself" without giving any details like libraries etc.  does not qualify as answer.

So I clicked the "Recommend deletion" button. Unfortunately, all the available items didn't seem to match, except perhaps "No reason needed" (may not be the exact wording and I don't have a screenshot).

What's the "correct" answer for this review?